# make ignores my python bash alias

Tags: makefile, bash

My CentOS 5.5 server has both Python 2.4 and Python 2.7 installed (to `/opt/python2.7.2`). In my `~/.bash_profile` I have two aliases pointing to my Python 2.7 install and my `PATH` configured as:

```
alias python=/opt/python2.7.2/bin/python
alias python2.7=/opt/python2.7.2/bin/python
PATH=$PATH:/opt/python2.7/bin
```

There's also a symbolic link I created as well:

```
ln -sf /opt/python2.7.2/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7
```

I have a `Makefile` which has the following lines:

```
pythonbuild:
        python setup.py build
```

To my surprise I found that Python 2.4 is being invoked and not Python 2.7.

I have to explicitly specify `python2.7`:

```
pythonbuild:
        python2.7 setup.py build
```

Are bash aliases ignored by `make`? I am guessing `make` uses `PATH` to locate the first `python` executable (which happens to be Python 2.4) instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From `bash(1)`:

```
   Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive,
   unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt
   (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS
   below).
```

While you might be able to use something like `SHELL=/bin/bash -O expand_aliases` in your `Makefile`, I think keeping an explicit dependency upon the newer Python in your `Makefile` is *much* better than keeping the dependency hidden in your *user* `~/.bash_profile` file.

Instead, put `PYTHON=/opt/python2.7/bin/python` into your `Makefile`, and then you can just use:

```
pythonbuild:
    $(PYTHON) setup.py build
```

in your rules.

The best part is you can easily change which Python interpreter you use on the command line:

```
make PYTHON=/tmp/python-beta/bin/python pythonbuild
```

If you deploy it to another site, it is just *one* line in the `Makefile` that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround with grep and awk:**

The advantage of this solution is that if I change the alias in the ~/.bash_profil or ~/.bashrc, it is automatically adopted by my makefile as well.

**Description:**

I want to use the **alias lcw** in my makefile, which is defined like in my ~/.bashrc file.

**.bashrc**

```
...
alias lcw='/mnt/disk7/LCW/productiveVersion/lcw.out'
...
```

I use also the definition of a varialble as presented in the other solutions, but I directly read its value from the bashrc by using grep and awk.

**makefile**

```
LCW= $(shell grep alias\ lcw= ~/.bashrc | awk -F"'" '{print $$2}')

.PHONY: std
std:
    $(LCW)
```

As you see the lcw alias is called by the command `$(LCW)` from the makefile.

**Note:**

My solution assumes that the alias in the bashrc is defined within ' ' characters.

Comment: Appreciated and will keep this technique in find.

Answer (score 1):

aliases are typically just used by interactive shells

Note only that, I think that `make` does not always invoke the shell
Your best bet is to be explicit about the paths you want to use